# Blank frame/item in Owl Carousel 2 loop

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel-2

I am using owl carousel 2 on home page of https://staging.thomasfarms.kitchen/ to show four slides. The loop option is set to true. The problem is happening on touch based devices (iphone/safari browser in my experience) where a slide items randomly render blank on sliding to next frame. Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you do not have extra closing tags. make sure all tags are close ex...
2. make sure you do not have extra white spaces.